# Is there a possible link between the word cuff and scuff?

Tags: etymology

The word scuff is of Scottish and perhaps Scandinavian skufa , skyfa  “to shove, push aside.” That seems similar to the verb cuff - to strike with an open hand.  Both were from an unknown origin cuff is perhaps from the Swedish kuffa  meaning to thrust or push. Both are sourced from etymology.com
Cuffing a sleeve pushes it out of the way.

Comment: English [_sk_-initial words](http://websites.umich.edu/~jlawler/sk.pdf) tend to refer to two-dimensional extended meanings, like _sky, skip, skate, skin,_ and _scuff_. They refer either to something flat and extended, or to contact with something flat and extended, especially motion across it.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [OnlineEtymologyDictionary](https://www.etymonline.com/word/scuff):

scuff (v.):

1768, "to walk (through or over something) without raising the feet," originally Scottish, a word "Of uncertain and possibly mixed origin" [OED], probably from a Scandinavian source related to Old Norse skufa, skyfa "to shove, push aside" (from Proto-Germanic *skubanan, from PIE *skeubh- "to shove;" see shove (v.)).

cuff (n.):

"bottom of a sleeve," mid-14c., cuffe "hand covering, mitten, glove," perhaps from Medieval Latin cuffia, cuphia "head covering," which is of uncertain origin, perhaps ultimately from Greek.